# Angularjs interceptor causes error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to create an interceptor for my sample angular.js app. Here's my config code:

```
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('failedRequestInterceptor');
```

});

and my interceptor

```
angular.module('sandboxApp').factory('failedRequestInterceptor', function ($q) {
return {
    'response': function (config) {
        console.log("test");
    }
}
```

});

it displays "test" string in my console, but immidiatly after that i got error "response is undefined" and application fail's to load.

Perhaps this has something to do with using yeoman and tools included with it, here is exact error text from console :

```
Error: response is undefined handleRequestFn/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16002:11 processQueue@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13137:27 scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13153:27 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14353:16 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14169:15 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14457:13 done@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9614:36 completeRequest@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9804:7 requestLoaded@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9745:1
```

return logFn.apply(console, args);

Comment: please remove the single quote from 'response'

Comment: I have already tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow this method of code:

### Interceptor function:

```
var interceptor = function ($q, $location) {
    return {
        response: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
};
```

### Interceptor injection:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but is there a way i can move interceptor to independent file ?

Comment: you can put it in myfile.js but make sure the script tag for it is above your app.js one